# 2D Matrix doens't work, should I multiply?

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, transform, linear-algebra

I have created 5 different matrices, and after that's done I multiply them together but it doesn't work...
I have tried multiply ways of solving this but with no success, I have checked my math many times on the matrix stuff and I dont think that's the problem, the problem is when I add them together.

```
    private Matrix4f getTransformMatrix(){
        Matrix3f translationMatrix = new Matrix3f().initTranslationIdentity(translation.getX(), translation.getY());
        Matrix3f scaleMatrix = new Matrix3f().initScaleIdentity(scale.getX(), scale.getY());
        Matrix3f shearXMatrix = new Matrix3f().initShearXIdentity(shear.getX());
        Matrix3f shearYMatrix = new Matrix3f().initShearYIdentity(shear.getY());
        Matrix3f rotationMatrix = new Matrix3f().initRotationIdentity(rotationAngle);
        return new Matrix4f().translate2Dto3D(translationMatrix.mul(scaleMatrix).mul(shearXMatrix).mul(shearYMatrix).mul(rotationMatrix));
}
```

Here's the init.... from matrix3f

```
    public Matrix3f initIdentity(){
    m[0][0] = 1; m[0][1] = 0; m[0][2] = 0;
    m[1][0] = 0; m[1][1] = 1; m[1][2] = 0;
    m[2][0] = 0; m[2][1] = 0; m[2][2] = 1;
    return this;
}

public Matrix3f initTranslationIdentity(float x, float y) {
    m[0][0] = 1; m[0][1] = 0; m[0][2] = x;
    m[1][0] = 0; m[1][1] = 1; m[1][2] = y;
    m[2][0] = 0; m[2][1] = 0; m[2][2] = 1;
    return this;
}

public Matrix3f initRotationIdentity(double angle) {
    float cos = (float) Math.cos(angle);
    float sin = (float) Math.sin(angle);
    m[0][0] = cos;  m[0][1] = sin; m[0][2] = 0;
    m[1][0] = -sin; m[1][1] = cos; m[1][2] = 0;
    m[2][0] = 0;    m[2][1] = 0;   m[2][2] = 1;
    return this;
}

public Matrix3f initScaleIdentity(float x, float y) {
    m[0][0] = x; m[0][1] = 0; m[0][2] = 0;
    m[1][0] = 0; m[1][1] = y; m[1][2] = 0;
    m[2][0] = 0; m[2][1] = 0; m[2][2] = 1;
    return this;
}

public Matrix3f initShearXIdentity(float shearX) {
    m[0][0] = 1; m[0][1] = shearX; m[0][2] = 0;
    m[1][0] = 0; m[1][1] = 1; m[1][2] = 0;
    m[2][0] = 0; m[2][1] = 0; m[2][2] = 1;
    return this;
}

public Matrix3f initShearYIdentity(float shearY) {
    m[0][0] = 1;      m[0][1] = 0; m[0][2] = 0;
    m[1][0] = shearY; m[1][1] = 1; m[1][2] = 0;
    m[2][0] = 0;      m[2][1] = 0; m[2][2] = 1;
    return this;
}
```

And here's the translating from 2d to 3d matrix

```
    public Matrix4f translate2Dto3D(Matrix3f m2){
    m[0][0] = m2.get(0, 0); m[0][1] = m2.get(0, 1); m[0][2] = 0;    m[0][3] = m2.get(0, 2);
    m[1][0] = m2.get(1, 0); m[1][1] = m2.get(1, 1); m[1][2] = 0;    m[1][3] = m2.get(1, 2);
    m[2][0] = 0;            m[2][1] = 0;            m[2][2] = 1;    m[2][3] = 0;
    m[3][0] = 0;            m[3][1] = 0;            m[3][2] = 0;    m[3][3] = 1;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: So what eaxactly is the problem here? I would recommend starting out with a simple example (say two translations or a translation and rotation) and directly looking on the resulting matrices to see if it makes sence. Also not that the (old deprecated matrix stack of the) GL typically uses column-major order, while your matrices are stored row-major (although with the programmable pipeline, this does not really matter any more)

Comment: I confused if I should add or multiply every matrices. In 3D you multiply.

Comment: You should multiply. The dimensionality of the vector space does not really matter for these transformations